# one single md5sum process on multiple input strings (via xargs ?)

Tags: bash

Consider the following three commands:

```
$ echo -n "string1" | md5sum
34b577be20fbc15477aadb9a08101ff9  -

$ echo -n "string2" | md5sum
91c0c59c8f6fc9aa2dc99a89f2fd0ab5  -

$ echo -n "string3" | md5sum
9e6dc8685bf3c1b338f2011ace904887  -
```

Now, we would like to have a command functioning like that:

```
$ echo -n "string1 string2 string2" | xargs md5sum
34b577be20fbc15477aadb9a08101ff9  -
9e6dc8685bf3c1b338f2011ace904887  -
9e6dc8685bf3c1b338f2011ace904887  -
```

Howevery, the output of

```
$ echo -n "string1 string2 string2" | xargs md5sum
```

is:

```
md5sum: string1: No such file or directory
md5sum: string2: No such file or directory
md5sum: string3: No such file or directory
```

Can you help us fix this ?

- We do not want to execute 3 processes for md5sum, we would really like to execute 1 process on 3 input strings (this is why xargs came into play... right?)
- We do not want to write any file to disk, we want it to be as fast as RAM accessing.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, not unless told to; by default it passes as many arguments as it can fit to each invocation. However, if md5sum receives arguments, it expects them each to be a filename.

Comment: Is there a reason to use md5sum for this, vs, say, Python with the [`hashlib` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib)?

Comment: ok, so basically we need to quit bash for this and go to python or java... all right, let's go for it. thanks for quick reply.

Comment: No need to "quit bash". md5sum isn't built into / part of bash either (and, for that matter, neither is xargs) -- you're using tools that aren't part of bash itself no matter what; using a Python module from a shell function isn't so different.

Comment: OK, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`md5sum` does not support any usage mode where a single invocation can read more than one distinct item to hash from stdin. Consequently, no possible combination of `xargs` or other shell tools can invoke it in a manner that does what you want. (Creative use of process substitution might be possible on platforms where `md5sum` allows named FIFOs to be passed to it as arguments, but on at least one platform where I tested, the command works only on regular files).

Consider using a different tool:

```
hashmany() {
    python -c '
import hashlib, sys
for arg in sys.argv[1:]: print hashlib.md5(arg).hexdigest()
' "$@"
}
```

...thereafter, your code can run:

```
hashmany string1 string2 string3
```

...with the output:

```
34b577be20fbc15477aadb9a08101ff9
91c0c59c8f6fc9aa2dc99a89f2fd0ab5
9e6dc8685bf3c1b338f2011ace904887
```

Comment: @123, that's one invocation of md5sum per string, which the OP explicitly does not want.

Comment: You have to md5sum each string separately though?

Comment: @123, correct, they're requesting a distinct md5sum generated for each input string, but *without* multiple distinct command invocations. My first thought was to use process substitution -- `md5sum <(printf '%s' string1) <(printf '%s' string2) <(printf '%s' string3)` -- but at least locally, my md5sum implementation insists on regular files; even if that's not true of all implementations, I'd rather not spend time on something that won't be portable.